# Solrcloud- Force Leader election

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We have solr cluster and one collection with 5 nodes. Below are the example.

Collection Name: list_test

- Node1: 192.168.1.1 -- Leader
- Node2: 192.168.1.2 -- Active
- Node3: 192.168.1.3 -- Active
- Node4: 192.168.1.4 -- Active
- Node5: 192.168.1.5 -- Active
- Node6: 192.168.1.6 -- Active

  In some case Node1(Leader) server is down. Any one of nodes will became as a leader. After fixing the node1 issue the server became up to active node.

  **Our scenario is after fixing the node1 issue, we need node1 will back to as a leader node. Is it possible?**

**Note: Solr version 7.4.0**

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the new APIs for the leader election. I would suggest to take necessary replications enabled on your core or taking necessary backups or process to regenerate indexes in case of a Disaster (i.e. Disaster Recovery).

[Balance Shard Unique](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/collections-api.html#balanceshardunique)

[Re-Balance Leaders](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/collections-api.html#rebalanceleaders)

[Force Leaders](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/collections-api.html#forceleader)

> This is an expert level command, and should be invoked only when regular leader election is not working. This may potentially lead to loss of data in the event that the new leader doesn’t have certain updates, possibly recent ones, which were acknowledged by the old leader before going down.

Comment: Force Leaders - It should work when leader has not available.


               **In some case Node1(Leader) server is down. Any one of nodes will became as a leader. After fixing the node1 issue the server became up to active node.**
**Our scenario is after fixing the node1 issue, we need node1 will back to as a leader node.**